# Find inverse such that $A = A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm asked to find coefficients a, b and c for the following matrix $ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ such that it has an inverse $A^{-1}$ and such that $A^{-1} = A$. How would start on such a problem? I've tried calculating the inverse of the matrix but I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: Have you calculated the inverse of $A$? If so, then all that remains is just compare the coefficients for all entries of the matrix.

Comment: Calculating $A^{-1}$ gives you the entries of $A^{-1}$ in terms of $a, b, c$ and a condition on $a,b,c$. The identity $A^{-1}=A$ gives you further conditions on $a,b,c$. Now, the possibility that the resulting system of equations could be solved for a unique (or a few) triples $(a,b,c)$ is an unreasonable expectation, therefore you should not stop working if you realise that said goal is unachievable. Rather, you should either make an ansatz on some values of $a,b,c$ and hope that the system is sufficiently under-determined, or look for a parametric solution and then put in some values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A^{-1}$ exists $\Rightarrow$ $Det(A)=-bc \neq 0$ which means both $b$ and $c$ can not be $0$

$A^{-1} = A \Rightarrow A^2=I$

$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & 0 \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow A^2=\begin{pmatrix}a^2+bc &ab \\ ac & bc\end{pmatrix}=I$

$\begin{pmatrix}a^2+bc &ab \\ ac & bc\end{pmatrix}=I \Rightarrow bc=1$ and $a=0$